# How to set value for time input in HTML? (I am using Django)

Tags: html, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

Inside a form, I want to input time. For this I am using the HTML `input type="time"` . I tried to set a value, but it does not appear
[Time value just appears empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSzwz.png)

```
<input type="time" name="due_time" id="id_due_time" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="{{ todo.due_time }}">
```

This is how I tried to get it done.
When the time default value did not appear, I tried formatting it like this-

```
<input type="time" name="due_time" id="id_due_time" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="{{ todo.due_time|time:'h i A' }}">
```

But it still doesn't work...

I'm a newbie, and I'm not familiar with Javascript, so I would appreciate it if the answers were kept simple.

Views.py

```
@login_required
def view_todo(request, todo_pk):
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TodoForm(instance=todo)
        return render(request, 'todo/view_todo.html', {'todo': todo, 'form': form})

    else:
        try:
            form = TodoForm(request.POST, instance=todo)
            form.save()
            return redirect('current_todos')

        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'todo/create_todo.html',
                          {'form': TodoForm(), 'error': 'Error:Bad data passed in. Please try again'})
```

Models.py

```
class Todo(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
due_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tags = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from todo.models import Todo

class TodoForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'important', 'due_time', 'due_date', 'tags']
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you also show the related part in `views.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `<input type='time'>` element should be in `h:i:s` format.

So change

```
<input type="time" name="due_time" id="id_due_time" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="{{ todo.due_time|time:'h i A' }}">
```

to

```
<input type="time" name="due_time" id="id_due_time" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="{{ todo.due_time|time:'h:i:s' }}">
```